# Set time out event on a m() generated element

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have a `m("p.help")` element which is removed with a click event.

I also want the element to be removed automatically after a few seconds if not clicked. I need to set a time out on it. Setting time out does not work.

```
function help() {
  var text = `This is a service template. Use Service section to set the schedule`;

  var node = m("p.help", {
    onclick() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    },
  }, text);

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (node.parentNode) {
      node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
      console.log("removed");
      m.redraw();
    }
  }, 5000);

  return node;
}
```

The click event works fine but the time out does not work. It is not even triggered judging by the `console.log()`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks ciscoheat for the tip.

I had to put the timer in the controller for this to work.

So this one works fine:

```
function controller(init) {
  this.display = {
    help: true
  };
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.display.help = false;
    m.redraw();
  }, 5000);
}

function view(vm) {
  return m(".container", [
    (() => {
      var text = "Some text";
      if (vm.display.help) {
        return m("p.memo", {
          onclick() {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
          }
        }, text);
      }
    })(),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: did u check this condition if (node.parentNode)

Comment: Yes, it is in the code above.

Comment: i mean condition becoming true or not.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, you are right. Parent is not there. But how is this possible...

Comment: Ok. I got it. I think... When click event is triggered the node is already inserted in a parent, but when the timer is set the node does not have a parent yet. Silly me ... Thanks for the tip. Now, I need to remove the element without the parent node present. I guess plain old CSS class is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Mithril correctly, you should avoid DOM manipulation, leaving that to Mithril's fast diff algorithm.

Use a state variable instead, related to displaying the help paragraph that will be changed automatically after 5 seconds.

Here's a jsbin showing what I mean: http://jsbin.com/kixece/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It is a shame I did not figure this one out as I did precisely that in some other parts of the application. The only difference was I toggled the elements instead.The time out got me confused somehow. For some weird reason I assumed it should be in the view.